# How to add new Objects to an Object type array after initializing it once?

Tags: java, arrays, object

I need to add more elements to the following array (Edges in this case). How can i do it? I need a quick solution since there's no time to change the architecture. Is it possible to do? I tried copying everything from an this array to an ArrayList. But i get stuck with the object type mismatches.

**This is my Dijkstra class which contains the main method :**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Dijkstra {
public static Graph graphMappingTemp;
public static ArrayList<Edge> arrayListEdge;


public static Edge[] GRAPH = {
  new Edge("Sri Lanka", "UK", 46),
  new Edge("Sri Lanka", "USA", 65),
  new Edge("Sri Lanka", "Dubai", 20),
  new Edge("Sri Lanka", "Singapore", 20),
  new Edge("Sri Lanka", "Malaysia", 35),
  new Edge("USA", "UK", 35),
  new Edge("UK", "USA", 35),
  new Edge("UK", "Dubai", 26),
  new Edge("Dubai", "Sri Lanka", 20),
  new Edge("Singapore", "Sri Lanka", 20),
  new Edge("Singapore", "Malaysia", 35),
  new Edge("Singapore", "Australia", 110),
  new Edge("Malaysia", "New Zealand", 73),
  new Edge("New Zealand", "Singapore", 113),
  new Edge("New Zealand", "Australia", 43),
  new Edge("Australia", "Dubai", 150),};

public static Graph graphMapping = new Graph(GRAPH);


private static final String START = "UK";
private static final String END = "USA";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //graphMappingTemp = new Graph(GRAPH); //Create a new Graph
    //arrayListEdge = new ArrayList<Edge>(); //Create a new array list

    for (Edge edge : GRAPH) {
        arrayListEdge.add(edge); //copy all edges from Graph to ArrayList
    }

    //graphMapping = new Graph(arrayListEdge); //Create a new graph with the ArrayList

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    graphMapping.runDijkstrasAlgo(START);
    graphMapping.printLeastCostPath(END);

    addCountry(input);
    graphMapping.printAllPaths();



    /*removeCountry(input);
    graphMapping.printAllPaths();*/

    //arrayListEdge.add(new Edge("UK", "USA", 56));         //test code

    input.close();
}

//Search least cost path option
public void searchLCP(Scanner input) {
    System.out.println("Please Enter the Origin : ");
    String inputOrigin = input.next();

    System.out.println("Please Enter the Destination : ");
    String inputDestination = input.next();
    //printLeastCostPath(inputDestination);
}

//Add country option
public static void addCountry(Scanner input){
    System.out.println("Please Enter your Country : ");
    String country = input.next();
    graphMapping.graph.put(country, new Vertex(country));

    //System.out.println(graphMapping.graph.containsKey("PAK"));

    System.out.println("Country successfully added!");

}

//Remove Country option
public static void removeCountry(Scanner input){
    System.out.println("Please Enter your Country : ");
    String country = input.next();
    System.out.println(country);
    graphMapping.graph.remove(country);

    System.out.println("Country successfully removed!");
}
```

}

**Edge class :**

```
public class Edge {
public final String country1, country2;
public final int distance;

public Edge(String country1, String country2,int distance) {
    this.country1 = country1;
    this.country2 = country2;
    this.distance = distance;
}

}
```

**Graph class :**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.NavigableSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;


public class Graph {
public final Map<String, Vertex> graph;

public Graph(Edge[] edges) {

    graph = new HashMap<>(edges.length);

    for (Edge e : edges) {
        if (!graph.containsKey(e.country1)){
            graph.put(e.country1, new Vertex(e.country1));
        }

        if (!graph.containsKey(e.country2)){
            graph.put(e.country2, new Vertex(e.country2));
        }
    }

    for (Edge e : edges) {
        graph.get(e.country1).neighbours.put(graph.get(e.country2),                          e.distance); // Since it is an directed graph
    }
}

public void runDijkstrasAlgo(String origin) {
    if(!graph.containsKey(origin)){
        System.err.printf("No starting vertex to be found \"%s\"\n", origin);
    }

    final Vertex source = graph.get(origin);
    NavigableSet<Vertex> q = new TreeSet<>();

    for (Vertex v : graph.values()) {
        v.previous = v == source ? source : null;
        v.distance = v == source ? 0 : Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        q.add(v);
    }

    runDijkstrasAlgo(q);
}

private void runDijkstrasAlgo(final NavigableSet<Vertex> q) {
    Vertex u,v;

    while (!q.isEmpty()) {
        u = q.pollFirst();
        if (u.distance == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            break;
        }

        for (Map.Entry<Vertex, Integer> a : u.neighbours.entrySet()) {
            v = a.getKey();

            final int alternateDistance = u.distance + a.getValue();

            if (alternateDistance < v.distance) { // shorter path to neighbour found
                q.remove(v);
                v.distance = alternateDistance;
                v.previous = u;
                q.add(v);
            }
        }
    }
}

 /** Prints a path from the source to the specified vertex */
   public void printLeastCostPath(String destination) {
      if (!graph.containsKey(destination)) {
         System.err.printf("No end vertex to be found \"%s\"\n", destination);
         return;
      }

      graph.get(destination).printLeastCostPath();
      System.out.println();
   }

   public void printAllPaths() {
       for (Vertex v : graph.values()) {
        v.printLeastCostPath();
        System.out.println();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: What does "I get stuck with the object type mismatches" mean?

Comment: I mean when i create an ArrayList, how do i pass that into the constructor of my Graph class? (Check the commented lines in the main method. )

Comment: Change Graph to take a `List<Edge>`.

Comment: I tried that earlier, but there was a problem with the way i have implemented. I'll check once more and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add more elements to the array if you define it explicitly like that. You can use an ArrayList if you want to have an array that can expand. Can you tell us what error it's giving and where?

UPDATE: As you're building up your array, keep it as an ArrayList. Then, when you're ready to convert it to an array (ie, when you're done growing it), you can do

```
Edge[] convertedArray = new Edge[thatArrayList.size()];
convertedArray = thatArrayList.toArray(convertedArray );
```

Comment: Asking for clarification should be done in comments, not with an answer.

Comment: I tried using the arraylist. but when i use it i have to change the Graph class to an ArrayList type and pass that. So the constructor can use it to create the new HashMap i'm creating there. Problem is, how to use an ArrayList there instead of of the current Edge[] array? Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: @david-conrad Even if along with the comment I also answer his question? Part of his question was whether it could be done, and I answered that.

Comment: @k9yosh Can't you just change Graph to take a `List<Edge>`? Change the HashMap ctor to use `edges.size()`, or just remove that since it's pointless anyway. You don't even need to change the syntax of the `for (Edge e : edges)` loops since the enhanced for loop syntax accepts either arrays or Iterables.